# Non-graphical output from pycallgraph

Tags: python, pycallgraph

I've started writing a small Python utility to cache functions. The available caching tools (`lru_cache`, [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/)) do not detect changes of sub-functions.

For this, I need a **Call Graph**. There exists an excellent tool in [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/latest/) by [Gerald Kaszuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11125/gerald-kaszuba). However, so far I've only got it to output function-name strings. What I need are either *function-objects* or *function-code-hashes.*

What I mean with these two terms: Let  `def foo(x): return x`, then `foo` is the function-object, and `hash(foo.__code__.co_code)` is the *function-code-hash*.

## What I have

You can see what I have [here](https://github.com/unapiedra/pycache). But below is a minimal example. The problem I have in this example, is that I can't go from a function name (the string) to the function definition again. I'm trying with `eval(func)`.

So, I guess there are two ways of solving this:

1. Proper `pycallgraph.output`, or some otherway to get what I want directly from Pycallgraph.
2. Dynamically loading the function from the `function.__name__` string.

---

```
import unittest
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput

class Callgraph:
    def __init__(self, output_file='callgraph.png'):
        self.graphviz = GraphvizOutput()
        self.graphviz.output_file = output_file

    def execute(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        with PyCallGraph(output=self.graphviz):
            ret = function(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graph = dict()
        for node in self.graphviz.processor.nodes():
            if node.name != '__main__':
                f = eval(node.name)
                self.graph[node.name] = hash(f.__code__.co_code)
        return ret

    def unchanged(self):
        '''Checks each function in the callgraph whether it has changed.
        Returns True if all the function have their original code-hash. False otherwise.
        '''
        for func, codehash in self.graph.iteritems():
            f = eval(func)
            if hash(f.__code__.co_code) != codehash:
                return False
        return True

def func_inner(x):
    return x
def func_outer(x):
    return 2*func_inner(x)

class CallgraphTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testChanges(self):
        cg = Callgraph()
        y = cg.execute(func_outer, 3)
        self.assertEqual(6, y)
        self.assertTrue(cg.unchanged())
        # Change one of the functions
        def func_inner(x):
            return 3+x
        self.assertFalse(cg.unchanged())
        # Change back!
        def func_inner(x):
            return x
        self.assertTrue(cg.unchanged())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by patching [`tracer.py`](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph/blob/develop/pycallgraph/tracer.py) with the appropriate hashes.

```
         # Work out the current function or method
         func_name = code.co_name
+        func_hash = hash(code.co_code)
```

I am calculating the value just where the function name is saved. Later on, you'd obviously also need to save that value. I am doing that with a dictionary where the `func_name` is the key and the hash is the value. In the function where nodes are created I am then assigning this to a new field in `stat_group`.